Server configuration for video on demand app for 1000 users
We are trying to use cloud servers to provide video on demand service (a much simplified version of Netflix in a single city).
The requirements are: maximum of 1500 users with 50%(~800) concurrent users at peak hour.
No/very low lag and buffer is a priority 720p video quality average 350mb file size
We currently have access to 140gb ram, 40cpu, 500gb ssd server.(storage can be increased).
What kind of configuration of server would be recommended? Will our current server be able to serve this with some modifications? Thank you in advance for ur response
@chopper3

To support 800 concurrent users streaming 720p videos, consider using a CDN to reduce latency and buffering. Implement load balancing to distribute the load and ensure you have sufficient network bandwidth. Your current server might be a good start, but you may need to scale up storage, CPU, and RAM based on usage.

Thank you. The thing about this project is it will only be confined to a single city. And it is not Ina very developed country so cdns mostly aren't very close. And the user base will ever be a maximum of 1500. This is why I didn't consider cdns.
